# Insert data with insert_batch

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, batch-file

I'm using the following statement to insert data in mysql with codeigniter.

```
$this->db->insert_batch($table, $query);
```

`$query` is generated dynamically can have different number of columns on each  array element

and maybe the number of elements may differ on condition

```
    array (
        0 => array(
            'column1'=>'insert1',
            'column2'=>'insert2'
        ),
        1 => array(
            'column1'=>'insert1';
            'column2'=>'insert2',
            'column4'=>'insert4'
        )
)
```

could this cause an error or handles codigniter from deafult?

I'm building up the query as it follows

```
foreach ($sql_xml as $children) {
    $children = $this->xml2array($children);
    foreach ($children as $index => $child) {
        if ($child != 'feed_id') {
            $keys[$index] = $child;
        } 
    }
}

switch (strtolower($this->config[0]->affiliate)) {
    case 'case1':
        $target_xml = $target_xml->productItems;
        break;
    case 'case2':
        $target_xml = $target_xml;
        break;
    default :
        break;
}

$query = array();
$data = array();
foreach ($target_xml as $feeds) {
    $feeds = $this->xml2array($feeds);
    $columns = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($feeds));
    foreach ($columns as $index => $column) {            
        if (array_key_exists($index, $keys)) {
            if($column != ''){
            $data[$keys[$index]] = $column;
            $data['feed_id']   = $this->id;
            }
            //*TODO //$data['affiliate'] = "'.$this->config[0]->affiliate.'";
        }                
    }
   $query[] = $data;

}


if (count($query > 0)) {
 foreach ($query as $t){

        $this->db->insert($table, $t); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array's would need to have the same amount of "columns".
So what I would recommend is the following (setting certain columns to `null` if no there is no data):

```
array (
    0 => array(
        'column1' => 'insert1',
        'column2' => 'insert2',
        'column3' => null,
        'column4' => null
    ),
    1 => array(
        'column1' => 'insert1',
        'column2' => 'insert2',
        'column3' => 'insert3',
        'column4' => 'insert4'
    )
)
```

Also, your syntax is invalid and it would cause an error since you are using a `;` instead of an `,` on the first column insert.

Comment: thanks for feedback I just made a test and looked in the source and as you say need to have the same amount of "columns". I made a loop  foreach ($query as $t){
               $this->db->insert_batch($table, array($t));   
            } but I have to proof the viability of this query

Comment: You could probably just do a loop on building the `$query` instead of looping with the `insert_batch` method. Then just pass `$query` once to `insert_batch`.